# After AWS Cloudfront Setup Browser Info is Incorrect

Tags: wordpress

Setup AWS CloudFront for WordPress website but after CloudFront My Browser info showing CloudFront. I checked from all browsers "Chrome, Firefox, Safari Opera".

using  $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] for getting browser info. But it always return same browser "CloudFront"

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront strips user-agent header and replace it with CloudFront.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html